# dynamic memory violation

Tags: c++

I am developing Avionics Simulation Software which handles heavy use of STL containers and Dynamic Allocations.
 Ofcourse the code is meant to be robust however exceptions such as allocation errors tend to produce model crashes which stops the entire simulation (which is very bad during qualification for ex). 
 I would like to isolate modules with advanced exception handling so that an error in one module (can be set to a fault state for ex) does not stop the other modules from running. So far I was able to bypass the 
 allocation errors by using signalhandlerpointer and the debug assertion using _CrtSetReportMode; However for the following case the code just exits:

```
try // Completely Garbage Code
{
    vector<string> hulu;
    hulu.push_back("ERROR");
    vector<string>::iterator phulu = hulu.begin();
    hulu.erase(phulu);
    string hala = *phulu;
}
```

Is there a way to catch the above error with an exception of somesort?

Comment: Unfortunately dereferencing end or past is Undefined Behavior, no exception thrown. You may need to write your own iterator wrappers that can perform checking for you.

Comment: Your example has undefined behaviour according to all C++ standards due to dereferencing an invalidated iterator.  Essentially, regardless of what code is being run, your simulator will need to provide a virtual machine environment that traps all invalid usages of pointers (and iterators) and generates an exception.   [I'll leave the question alone of why you are seeking to have avionics code that uses dynamic memory allocation AT ALL - since, for most high-criticality avionics codes, dynamic memory allocation is actively discouraged due to the additional V&V effort introduced].

Comment: As a pilot, that is one scary thought....

Comment: @Peter: It was my understanding that this was a simulation, not avionics code. Avionics code has extremely strict programming rules like you've mentioned, and in a lot of cases they cannot use much of the STL anyway. Code like above would never pass inspection.

Comment: @AndyG - simulation environments that are used to support acceptance of avionics are often subject to requirements at least as strict as requirements on the avionics.

Comment: Are the "modules" separate threads?